# Boost.Log asynchronous logging with syslog backend

Tags: c++, asynchronous, logging, boost, syslog

I am implementing a wrapper on Boost.log for logging sync and async ways. As bellow I defined asychronous sink frontend with with `syslog_backend`.

```
typedef sinks::asynchronous_sink<
    sinks::syslog_backend,
    sinks::unbounded_ordering_queue<
    logging::attribute_value_ordering< unsigned int, std::less< unsigned int > >
>
> Async_syslog_sink;
```

But inside init() when I use this definition to create a backend and add to logging::core, an error was occured.

```
// Create a backend
boost::shared_ptr< Async_syslog_sink > sink(new Async_syslog_sink(
    keywords::facility = sinks::syslog::user,
    keywords::use_impl = sinks::syslog::native
));
sink->set_formatter(&my_formatter);
logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
```

The error is:

> /usr/include/boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp: In instantiation of
>   ‘boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::asynchronous_sink::asynchronous_sink(bool) [with SinkBackendT =
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::syslog_backend; QueueingStrategyT =
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::unbounded_ordering_queue > >]’:
>   /root/sample-logger/src/Loggers/Async/AsyncLogger.h:314:9:
>   required from here
>   /usr/include/boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp:230:31: error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   ‘boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::unbounded_ordering_queue > >::unbounded_ordering_queue()’
>            m_FlushRequested(false)

How Can I have an asynchronous logger with syslog backend?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an ordering predicate in the `keywords::order` named parameter of the sink constructor. Given that you use `logging::attribute_value_ordering`, you should specify the attribute name based on which you want to order log records when constructing the predicate. For example:

```
keywords::order = logging::attribute_value_ordering< unsigned int, std::less< unsigned int > >("RecordID")
```